R packageのtidychatmodelsを用いる際にtime_outを管理する方法について
R言語のtidychatmodelsパッケージを用いてR環境内にchatbotの作成に取り組んでいます。
modelでgpt-4-turboを選択し、コードを実行すると以下のエラーが発生します。
add_modelの引数をgpt-3.5-turboとすると実行はされるのですが、hallucinationが出現し、意味の無い回答となってしまったため、gpt-4-turboを用いたいと思い下記コードの実行を行っています。
以下のサイトがtidychatmodelsのgithubのページと入門者向けの制作者による解説サイトです。どちらもtimeoutの管理をどの関数で行うかは記載がありませんでした。
https://github.com/AlbertRapp/tidychatmodels/tree/master
https://albert-rapp.de/posts/20_tidychatmodels/20_tidychatmodels
どうか問題の解決方法を知っている方、ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。
環境
Windows 11 Pro
R 4.4

実際のコード
#.envはopen_ai_api_key="自身のOPEN_AI_API_KEYを入力"がファイルの内容です。
dotenv::load_dot_env('.env')
library(tidyverse)
library(tidychatmodels)
chat_openai <- create_chat('openai', Sys.getenv('open_ai_api_key'))
chat_openai_instructor<-chat_openai_translater<-chat_openai |>
  add_model('gpt-4-turbo') |>
  add_params('temperature' = 0.2) |>
  add_message(
    role = 'system',
    message = 'You are a helpful assistant.'
  ) |> 
  add_message(
    # default role = 'user'
    message = 'Please tell me the R code that extends the time before OpenAIAPI times out using curl.
        '
  ) |> 
  perform_chat()
answers <- chat_openai_instructor |> extract_chat(silent = TRUE)
answers$message[3] |> cat()

メッセージ
Error in `httr2::req_perform()`:
! Failed to perform HTTP request.
Caused by error in `curl::curl_fetch_memory()`:
! Timeout was reached: [api.openai.com] SSL/TLS connection timeout
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

